# Chinese Visa: Maximum duration of longest stay with double entry

Tags: visas, china, multiple-entry

I want to apply for a tourist double entry visa for China. I intend to stay for around 15 days in China. Then leave China for around 1 month (will be in Taiwan) and then back to China for another 15 days.

Counts the 'Maximum duration of longest stay (days)' on the visa website  for each stay or do I need to calculate both entries together? I thought I will put these values in the form, but not sure if that is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here, the form is asking for the duration of your longest stay. Since both of your stays are for 15 days, you should put 15 in this field.

As the [other answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/149162/89966) mentions, there is no problem in asking for 30 days but 15 days is the correct entry.

Answer (score 0):

It's the maximum duration of anyone's stay. In your case, that is 15 days, so requesting 30 days is fine. You could also ask for 15, but if your stay got extended or was off by a day you would be overstaying your visa.

Usually the stay they grant is 30 days on a double-entry visa.

Comment: I'm not sure this is right, surely it is 15 days since that is the length of the longest stay.

Comment: @Daniil There’s no problem asking for 30 when your expected itinerary only calls for 15.

Comment: The OP asks *Counts the 'Maximum duration of longest stay (days)' on the visa website for each stay or do I need to calculate both entries together?*. Saying requesting *x* is fine doesn't answer the question. I'm close to giving this a -1

Comment: @Daniil Edited to clarify.

Comment: *Usually the stay they grant is 30 days on a double-entry visa.* Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @Daniil Experience over about half a dozen (double entry) visas. They sometimes won't give you as much as you ask for. For example, it's unlikely to get multiple entry (not double) without some history of previous visas provided (old passport etc.).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100615/discussion-between-daniil-and-spehro-pefhany).